# How to show or hide dynamic textbox based on dynamic selected radiobutton before submit webform in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display or hide a dynamically created textbox when we select a radiobutton also dynamically created in a web form before clicking on the submit button in a web form with asp.net?

In other words, when loading the form and before sending the form, if the client chooses to click on a radio button, the text box is hidden and if he chooses another radiobutton, the textbox is hidden

Comment: You can do it with javascript. This a superficial answer I know, but you should also know your questions must include some code snippets.

Comment: yes i can give you code.

Comment: public void CreateGroupeM(string id)
  {
   string contenuBtn1 = "";
   
   contenuBtn1 = "Confirmé";
  
   RadioButtonList rblist = new RadioButtonList();

   ListItem lI1 = new ListItem(contenuBtn1, "1");
   
   lI1.Attributes.Add("class", "classlI1");
   
   rblist.Items.Add(lI1);

   rblist.ID = id;
   rblist.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
   rblist.CssClass = "rowRDB col-md-12 font-weight-bold";
   pnl1.Controls.Add(rblist);
              }

Comment: this function is used to create Dynamic RDB

Comment: public void CreateTextBoxM(string id)
  {
   TextBox txt = new TextBox();
   txt.ID = id;
   txt.CssClass = "rowTXT col col-md-8";
   txt.MaxLength=50;
   pnl1.Controls.Add(txt);
  }

Comment: this function is used to create a dynamic text box

Comment: <%--Debut Division 2--%>
  <div class="container table-responsive-sm" id="con5">
   <%--II Debut Bloc repetitif differentes prestaions--%> 
   <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" class="form-group col-12 table-responsive-sm" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Direction="LeftToRight">
   </asp:Panel>
   <%--II Fin Bloc repetitif differentes prestaions--%> 
           
   <div class="w-100 py-1"></div>
  <%--Fin Division 2--%>

Comment: this is the panel container in my webform wich contain text box and raadiobutton created dynamicly

Comment: and in the load function we call the functions to create our dynamic element :

Comment: int i1 = pnl1.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.CreateGroupeM("rdbDynamicList" + i1);

    pnl1.Controls.Add(divEspace7);
    ////***********************************************************************
int i7 = pnl1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.CreateTextBoxM("txtDynamic" + i7);

Comment: You can edit your question and use the code tag for inserting your snippets.